# Remove all lines that contain more than one '@' using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have like that:

> a1@305@
>
> a50@21
>
> b6@@

The **first** and the **last** lines should be removed because they contain more than one `@`

What should be the regex for that?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any pattern yet? What if  a line contains three `@`s?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- Omg, I meant to remove all the lines that contain more than one `@` - Sorry I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply going like this would do it:

```
.*@.*@.*
```

That assumes you would like to find all lines with 3 @s or 4@s too though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :)

```
^([^@]+)?@(([^@]+)?@)+([^@]+)?$
```

It's good idea to use `^` and `$` modifiers to terminate regex matching early.